Is the binomial expansion an alternating series?
Show for $x>0$, $\sqrt{x^4+1}=x^2+\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{8x^6}+\textit{E}(x)$ where $|E(x)|\leq\frac{1}{16x^{10}}$.
Here I think the binomial expansion for real numbers is used and it turns out to be an alternating series so the absolute value of E(x) is less than the last term used. I have 2 questions.
How is this valid for small but positive x since the sequence for the alternating series need to be decreasing for the last term to be used as the error term. If $x=10^{-5}$ then $\frac{1}{2x^2}\leq\frac{1}{8x^6}$.
Also we have $\sqrt{a+b}=\Sigma^{\infty}_{k=0}C(1/2,k)a^{1/2-k}b^k$. The expression above is obtained by letting a=x^4 and b=1 and if we interchange these we get $\sqrt{1+x^4}=1+\frac{1}{2}x^4-\frac{1}{8}x^8+\frac{1}{16}x^{12}+...$
How is $x^2+\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{8x^6}+\frac{1}{16x^{10}}+...=1+\frac{1}{2}x^4-\frac{1}{8}x^8+\frac{1}{16}x^{12}+...$ ?

Based on the structure of the series I think this is intended to be an asymptotic expansion in the regime where $x \to \infty$ is large, which should be specified by whoever gave you this problem. Otherwise the terms here don't get smaller, as you say. The expansion you wrote down is an expansion in the regime where $x \to 0^{+}$ is small.

Let
$$
q=16 \left(\sqrt{x^{4}+1}-x^{2}-\frac{1}{2 x^{2}}+\frac{1}{8 x^{6}}\right) x^{10}.
$$
We need to show that $|q|\le 1$.
Set $x=y^{1/4}$, $y\ge 0$, then
$$
q=16 y^3\sqrt{1 +1/y}-(16 y^{3}+8 y^{2})+2 y
$$
First, observe that $q\ge 0$. Indeed, for $y>0$
$$
q=\frac{-64 y^4}{16 y^3\sqrt{1 +1/y}+(16 y^{3}+8 y^{2})}+2y
=2y\left(1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 +\frac 1y}+1+\frac1{2y}}\right)>0.
$$
Next,
$$
1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 +\frac 1y}+1+\frac1{2y}}<\frac1{2y}
$$
which is definitely true for $y\le 1/2$ and for $y>1/2$
$$
1-\frac1{2y}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 +\frac 1y}+1+\frac1{2y}}
$$
since
$$
\sqrt{1 +\frac 1y}+1+\frac1{2y}<\frac{2}{1-\frac1{2y}}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\sqrt{1 +\frac 1y}<\frac{4 y^{2}+1}{(4y-2) y}
\Longleftrightarrow
1 +\frac 1y<\frac{(4 y^{2}+1)^2}{(4y -2)^2 y^2}
\Longleftrightarrow
1+\frac{16y^2}{(2y- 1)^2}>0
$$
which is definitely true for $y>1/2$.
